# Regex does not work on nearly identical raw data in Splunk

Tags: asp.net, regex, pcre, splunk

Im using Splunk (data monitoring) and I have a regex that checks our logs and needs to return some info of a job failure. The regex works pretty good but for one job failure it does not output anything but for another nearly identical one it does. I've tried with regex checker but don't get any definitive answer.
Splunk regular expressions are PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) and use the PCRE C library.

The regex in question:
`"(Exception \W: |Exception: |Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException | Exception\s \(\dx\d{8}\)\: | Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException\s \(\dx\d{8}\)\: )(?<ErrInfo2>[A-Za-z0-9\s_@.\/<#&->+?=:$!',\\\)(;-]+)"`

**Piece of text it works on :**

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 76) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

**Piece of text it *doesn't* work on:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'collecting.IstHochrechnung' with unique index 'IX_IstHochrechnung_Year_CostUnitId_CostCenterId'. The duplicate key value is (2022, 2605, 333).

The part `Exception\s \(\dx\d{8}\)\:` takes care of the (0x80131904): entry so i dont see why it would remain empty.

Any help is more than appreciated!!

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException\s \(\dx\d{8}\)\ this part needs to take into account the namespace System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is using the namespace Microsoft.Data and the other System.Data. You just need to make it so it doesn't matter.

```
(Exception \W: |Exception: | ?\w{1,}.Data.SqlClient.SqlException\s ?\(\dx\d{8}\)\: )(?<ErrInfo2>[A-Za-z0-9\s_@.\/<#&->+?=:$!',\\\)(;-]+)
```

This still cares about the namespace, but has made it so that the first segment can be any word. E.g. test.Data.SqlClient.

I always test on regex101.com

Here is a smaller query as well... noticed you had a fair bit of duplication.

```
[\w\.]{1,}Exception ?\(0x\d{8}\)?: ?(?<ErrInfo2>[A-Za-z0-9\s_@.\/<#&->+?=:$!',\\\)(;-]+)
```

Comment: you are a hero man! I took me 2h and still didn't see it... Now I see it was fixing on the Microsoft part and now i see i got other entries with other words befe .Data. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, it has happened to us all when looking at a problem for too long :)